# Clustering structured (numeric) and text data simultaneously

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout

Folks,
I have a bunch of documents (approx 200k) that have a title and abstract. There is other meta data available for each document for example category - (only one of cooking, health, exercise etc), genre - (only one of humour, action, anger) etc. The meta data is well structured and all this is available in a MySql DB.

I need to show to our user related documents while she is reading one of these document on our site. I need to provide the product managers weight-ages for title, abstract and meta data to experiment with this service.

I am planning to run clustering on top of this data, but am hampered by the fact that all Mahout Clustering example use either **DenseVectors** formulated on top of numbers, or **Lucene based text vectorization**.

The examples are either numeric data only or text data only. Has any one solved this kind of a problem before. I have been reading Mahout in Action book and the Mahout Wiki, without much success.

I can do this from the first principles - extract all titles and abstracts in to a DB, calculate TFIDF & LLR, treat each word as a dimension and go about this experiment with a lot of code writing. That seems like a longish way to the solution.

That in a nutshell is where I am trapped - am I doomed to the first principles or there exist a tool / methodology that I somehow missed. I would love to hear from folks out there who have solved similar problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a text similarity problem here and I think you're thinking about it correctly. Just follow any example concerning text. Is it really a lot of code? Once you count the words in the docs you're mostly done. Then feed it into whatever clusterer you want. The term extractions is not something you do with Mahout, though there are certainly libraries and tools that are good at it.

Comment: Thanks Sean, will let you know how this goes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually working on something similar, but without the need of distinciton between numeric and text fields.

I have decided to go with the [semanticvectors](http://code.google.com/p/semanticvectors/) package which does all the part about tfidf, the semantic space vectors building, and the similarity search. It uses a lucene index.

Please note that you can also use the [s-space](https://github.com/fozziethebeat/S-Space) package if semanticvectors doesn't suit you (if you go down that road of course).

The only caveat I'm facing with this approach is that the indexing part can't be iterative. I have to index everything every time a new document is added, or an old document is modified. People using semanticvectors say they have very good indexing times. But I don't know how large their corpora are. I'm going to test these issues with the wikipedia dump to see how fast it can be.